# How to pass dropdown list value from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this in controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.CurrencyId = new SelectList(CommonDbService.GetAllCurrency(),"Id","Name");
    return View();
}
```

I have class where i populate this dropdown and show it in view :

```
public static Currency[] GetAllCurrency()
{
    Currency [] currency  = Currency.GetAllCurrencies();
    return currency;
}
```

This is my view :

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Currency)
@Html.DropDownList("CurrencyId","Select currency...")
```

I need to get value from dropdown list in view and pass it to controller :

```
Model.Currency.Find(dropdown list value); <--- here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing it to the controller on POST? If so, make sure your post method has a model defined as an input value, make the view strongly-typed using that model, and use `@Html.DropDownListFor`. The selected value will automatically be put in the model and passed back on POST.

Comment: I'm trying to pass value to controller on submit button

Comment: Which would be, by definition, on the POST.

Comment: Can i use @Html.DropDownListFor on view but without populating data on view? Because on my way im populating data in controller and send them to dropdown list in view....thats how i want to do that

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.